# Instantiating and calling standard php class in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am experimenting with datatables and php, and trying to get an example server side script working at https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html. I'm working with codeigniter.

As Part of the script I have the following:

```
require( 'ssp.class.php' );

          echo json_encode(
              SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
          );
```

I have downloaded the class and placed it within the application/libraries folder. How do I instantiate and use it in codeigniter. I don't think :

```
$this->load->library('ssp.class');
```

is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

There are some convention in CodeIgniter you have to follow. It is the file name must match with the class name. Instead you can do this ...

Create another library file `Ssp.php` and code something like this

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

// include external library
require_once 'ssp.class.php';

// extends the classname from included file
class Ssp extends Class_name
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

Now you can do this

```
$this->load->library('ssp');
```

from which you can use the methods of `ssp.class.php`. Is not the recommended way, I used to do this. Thanks!

Comment: After loading ssp as above can you use static methods like SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )?